# What is the function of init in Active Contour Model

Tags: image-processing, opencv, scipy

In practice of image processing using scikit-image, I didn't understand the role of constructing init numpy array in [Active Contour Model](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_active_contours.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-edges-plot-active-contours-py) example. Is it the red section drawn in the example astronaut image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Active contour is just refining your initial contour.

You could play yourself with the model :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: how did the red circle construct? is it through the init numpy array?

Comment: Yes, you may have other contour detection, and you use active_contour, for instance, to smooth the contour.

Comment: You can how the red dashed lines are plotted.
`ax.plot(init[:, 1], init[:, 0], '--r', lw=3)` 
Yes, simply the init path.

Comment: thanks for the answer